# Inequality conservation about convergence in law

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality, weak-convergence

I am trying to prove a claim about probability, and it is concluded if I can prove the following statement:

> Suppose $X_n \rightarrow X$ in law, and $\exists\, M>0$ s.t. $\forall\, n$, $E[|X_n|] \leq M$. Then $$E[|X|] \leq M$$

Is this statement true? And how can I prove this?

Comment: Don't you mean "Then$ E[|X|]\le M$" for your conclusion?  Otherwise, what does $X$ have to do in your question?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I have to prove “$E[|X|] \leq M$”.

Comment: @Blue you can edit your post. Also: another possibility would be to combine [Skorokhod's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_representation_theorem) and Fatou's lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is *yes*.

Your assumption that $X_n\Rightarrow X$ implies $|X_n|\Rightarrow |X|$.
Let $G_n(x)=P[|X_n|>x]$ and $G(x)=P[|X|>x]$, so $E[|X_n|]=\int_0^\infty G_n(x)\,dx$ and $E[|X|]=\int_0^\infty G(x)\,dx$.  Now apply [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma), to learn that
$$\int_0^\infty \liminf_n G_n(x)\,dx\le\liminf_n E[|X_n|]\le M.$$
The integrand on the left is equal to $G$ at all continuity points of $G$, so differs from $G$ on a set of measure zero.  So the integral on the left is equal to $\int_0^\infty G(x)dx=E[|X|].$